# change VM USB settings via script dynamicaly

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware-player

Let's just say I have a Linux VM and I have written a script which sends some CAN messages over a CAN dongle out. Hence I connect the CAN dongle to my Windows PC and use the VM tool settings to "add a USB controller". Once I did that I can make use of the CAN dongle inside the Linux VM.

[image: Virtual Box USB Settings]

**Question**: Can I automate that via a script from Windows dynamically? Dynamically shouldn't be an issue since adding a USB controller to a VM also works on the fly. The questions is if I can automate that via a script.

What I want is to create an UI application which has a radio button for a Dongle connect to Windows and let me toggle if it should be allocated to Windows or the Linux VM.